# WP_MAIL() not sending attachments to Gmail

Tags: wordpress, email, gmail, attachment, wp-mail

I am trying to send a mail with an attachment using WordPress wp_mail functionality to Gmail(ahmedkaizur@gmail.com). Also tried another Gmail. I am not getting email in my mailbox.
`$runner = wp_mail( $receiver, $subject, $msg, $headers, $attachment );`

But, getting mail when I send mail without attachment.
`$runner = wp_mail( $receiver, $subject, $msg );`

---

But, getting mail to another email (kaizur@crebsol.com) if I send with/without attachment.

**Note:** kaizur@crebsol.com is a linked with gmail though it's a webmail.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code.

```
$attachment = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/reunion_pdf/reunion_reg_'.$user_id.'.pdf');      

//$headers = 'From: ' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . ' <' . get_bloginfo( 'admin_email' ) . '>' . "\r\n\\";

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
$headers[] = 'From: '.get_option( 'blogname' ).' <'.get_option( 'admin_email' ).'>';

// $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
// $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
// $headers[] = 'From: '.get_option( 'blogname' ).' <'.get_option( 'admin_email' ).'>';

$subject = sprintf( __( '[%s] Payment Received', 'wp-user-frontend' ), get_bloginfo( 'name' ) );

$msg = sprintf( __( 'New payment received at %s.', 'wp-user-frontend' ), get_bloginfo( 'name' ) );
$msg .= ' You recieved ৳'.$amount.' for Reunion 2023 from '.$user_name.'('.$user_email.') (User ID : '.$user_id.').';
        
//$adminmail = get_option('admin_email');
//$adminmail = 'kaizur@crebsol.com';
$adminmail = 'ahmedkaizur@gmail.com';       
$receiver = array($adminmail);
$runner = wp_mail( $receiver, $subject, $msg, $headers, $attachment );
```

Comment: $headers[]= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"". PHP_EOL; 
$headers[]= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit". PHP_EOL;

Comment: you need use multipart/mixed; in header

Comment: @Vel - Awesome! Thanks for your cooperation. It's working. But, getting an extra file with NONAME title. Implemented code: $separator = '';
$headers = array();
$headers[]= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"". PHP_EOL; 
$headers[]= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit". PHP_EOL;

Comment: @Vel - No message getting as text. Getting an extra file with NONAME title which contains the message ($msg). This message is showing when the NONAME file is opened by txt file.

Comment: @Vel - Please check the SS. https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/33739176?key=09e647c47ccb99c6c2921dae43c54ef9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found the solution. I want to credit [Vel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3946728/vel).

Thanks for his valuable comment. I modified his code. And I replace the `$headers = array(); $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'; $headers[] = 'From: '.get_option( 'blogname' ).' <'.get_option( 'admin_email' ).'>';` with

`$headers[]= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit". PHP_EOL;`

And working fine.